# Wikidata examples and subclasses

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

The examples for counting instances at [query.wikidata.org](https://query.wikidata.org) (and elsewhere) use the `wdt:P31/wdt:P279*` property path. For example, the number of humans in Wikidata:

`SELECT (COUNT(?item) AS ?count)
WHERE {
    ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q5 .
}`

so that entities that are a subclass of human (I don't think this type exists, but think "nobel laureate", etc.) are included. But then other examples such as "women with most sitelinks and no image born in 1921 or later", which is truncated here:

`SELECT ?s ?desc ?linkcount
WHERE
{
  ?s wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ;   # human
     wdt:P21 wd:Q6581072 ;  # gender: female
     wdt:P569 ?born .
  FILTER (?born >= "1921-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime) .
 ...`

don't use the `wdt:P31/wdt:P279*` property path. Are these generally oversights (or perhaps done for speed?), or is the subclass property path not actually needed in these cases and I'm too dense to see why?

Comment: Well, you're absolutely correct. For 1) completeness and if 2) the types are not materialized you'd always have to use the path `wdt:P31/wdt:P279*`. You can check that there are instances that do not belong to `wd:Q5` directly but to one of its subclasses via `SELECT ?s
WHERE
{
  ?s wdt:P31/wdt:P279+ wd:Q5 
  filter not exists{?s wdt:P31 wd:Q5}
  }` - that said, it's just an example query, I don't think the author was thinking of completeness when writing the query resp. when describing the query with a single phrase.